# LinearLayout vs. ConstraintLayout with RecyclerView Items

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a problem whereby the layout for an item in a recyclerview displays properly when using `LinearLayout`, but displays nothing when converted to a `ConstaintLayout`.

The LL version:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fs_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff8800"
                tools:text="name"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fs_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0088ff"
                tools:text="type"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The context is a project which has not gone far beyond the "Master Detail" template, this view replaces the slightly simpler (single TextView) layout from that.  The above works as expected.  There are about 20 items initially and they all appear.

**Without *any* other changes**, swapping that layout for this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fs_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/fs_type"
                android:background="#ff8800"
                tools:text="name" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fs_type"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/fs_name"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:background="#0088ff"
                tools:text="type" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

None of the items added to the RecyclerView appear in the emulator, although a `Toast` shimmed into the Activity shows they are being added.  Changing the width to `wrap_content` doesn't make any difference.

Both layouts pass without error and appear as expected in the design view.

How can I figure out what's gone wrong here?  Again, *there are no other changes made*.  I am literally swapping one file for the other and rebuilding (and tried kicking it with "Invalidate caches...").

This is using `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3`.

Comment: I tried your XML code and it was working. Did you change any Java code?

Comment: Nope.  Just swapping one layout for another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the LayoutManager set in the "master detail" recyclerview template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 
    [...]
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"   <----------------- 
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_list_content"/>
```

Changing this to `GridLayoutManager` made everything appear properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try making layout height wrap_content.  I assume you want the view holder to wrap content, and if your Recycler View is wrap_content then the viewholder being match_parent will collapse.

Comment: The RecyclerView is `match_parent`, nested in a `Frame_Layout` that's also match parent in the Master-Detail stock layout.  Changing the TextView widths did not make any difference, should have mentioned that initially.